# aws loadbalancer,routeable confusion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm putting the instances behind the `aws loadbalancer`, I have configured the routable and attached the IGW to it, created the loadbalancer and added this instance to the aws loadbalancer every things work well, the endpoint URL of the AWS loadbalancer able to load the HTTP pages

Now i have removed the IGW from the route table and  tested it again, the AWS loadbalalncer endpoint URL not able to load the page, but the instace status shows in AWS loadbalancer as inService

Why the IGW is required when loadbalancer is configured over private subnet, it technically Mean it's a public subnet, which is blocking me to create a NAT inatance

Comment: By default, ELB creates an Internet-facing load balancer. If you want to load-balance instances in a private subnet then you need to create an internal load balancer. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-create-internal-load-balancer.html.

Answer (score 4):

A subnet without a default route pointing to the igw-xxxxxxxx Internet Gateway object is, by definition, a *private* subnet.  If you remove the igw from a public subnet, you now have a private subnet.

Placing an Internet-facing load balancer (ELB) in such a private subnet is incorrect.

It sounds as though you are making a commonly-made -- but incorrect -- assumption that the ELB should be configured in the same subnets as the instances behind it.  This is also incorrect.

Provision the ELB in public subnets, without regard to the subnets the instances behind it were placed in.

In summary:

- Internet-facing ELB requires a public subnet for placement.
- NAT instance requires a public subnet for placement.
- The instances that use these services (NAT and ELB) belong in different -- private -- subnets, different subnets than the ELB and NAT instances.
- ELB and NAT can be placed together in the same subnets, or separately, as long as the subnets are public (have the IGW as their default route) and are in the same availability zones.

Comment: It means we can't have outgoing connection from public subnet which are associated with the loadbalancer

Comment: No, it doesn't... If an instance has a public IP of its own, put it in a public subnet.  If it doesn't, then put it in a private subnet, then set the default route for that private subnet  to reference a NAT instance, which is in a public subnet.  ELB goes in a public subnet, even if the instances it is balancing do not.

Comment: So there is no way get an outgoing from instances(NO EIP or PIP) which is on public subnet and behind a loadbalancer

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, a public ELB needs to have public IP associated with it, otherwise, the client won't able able to resolve DNS to a routable IP. Is this right? But I can't find the PIP or EIP from the AWS console for a public ELB, why?

Comment: Public ELBs automatically get public IP addresses @chen.  They're not EIPs, they're assigned from a pool, but the instances behind the ELB can't use the ELB for outbound requests they initiate.     These addresses are also subject to change any time the ELB scales up or down or has maintenance, but the DNS mapping is all automatic when you point your hostname at the ELB hostname with an Alias or CNAME.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot do anything without the IGW attached to the routing table where the subnet is attached to.

Another way to do this is to spin off a NAT instance(can be found in AWS marketplace)  in the public subnet, add it to your private route table where your original instance is on (0.0.0.0/0 - instanceid) all the traffic will be routed through the NAT instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here mainly we have to see two things, provided subnet for the elasticloadbalancer is public or private.
Every VPC should have one IGW to connect to the public, every trafic should go through the IGW only. If VPC connected to the IGW, IGW distribute internet to the all instance which are in that VPC, if route table changed to the particular rt, internet traffic can send to only that instance. Here in ELB instance is in service because both are in the same VPC and can communicate each other means checks the status. This IGW will work main role when we are using the NAT.
Always we provide ip range for the IGW or rt as 0.0.0.0/0, it represents as public.
The following link will explain more : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html

Answer (score 0):

This small explanation might be helpful for someone.

Let me cover your two questions

1. the AWS loadbalalncer endpoint URL not able to load the page, but the instace status shows in AWS loadbalancer as inService

This is the default behaviour of load balancer , since internally load balancer and your instance may be in the same VPC so they are able to communicate that is why loadbalancer is showing inService status.

2. Second question Why the IGW is required when loadbalancer is configured over private subnet, it technically Mean it's a public subnet, which is blocking me to create a NAT inatance

You need IGW if you want to access any resources especially EC2 , Loadbalancer from internet. however if you put your load balancer in private subnet it means IGW is not associated with the subnet having loadbalancer in it and hence this load balancer is not accessible outside your VPC that is reason that you were not able to load your page.

NAT instance is usually used when you want your private subnet instances should be able to initiate request over internet and has nothing to do with normal load balancing setup unless and untill you want dont want to install any updates from internet to your instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access webpage publicly and removing the route entry IGW from the loadbalncer subnet.
The Subnet without IGW will become Private, Hence you can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

First, a subnet with route table that route traffic via the internet gateway (IGW) is a public subnet. An IGW is required because the subnets created in AWS VPC are internal IPs and as internal IPs are not routable via the internet, traffic to and fro EC2 instances that belongs to an internal IP needs a way to complete these request. This is where an IGW comes into play. The IGW allows your EC2 instance to make outbound request to the internet and allows other user/client to make inbound request to your ec2 instance.

A public subnet are group of IPs (called subnets) in your VPC that allows internet traffic to and fro your ec2 instance. A subnet without an Internet gateway is a private subnet. As you already guess no traffic is allowed in or out.

That said, instances in VPC which are in Private subnet still need to initiate an outbound request to the internet to download software or perform update. In this case you have to create and attach a NAT gateway or NAT instance to the private subnet. NAT Gateway and NAT instance only allow outbound traffic to the internet but not the the other way round. In some cases you might want your production EC2 to be in the private subnet and ELB in public subnet for security reason.

ELB usually belong to the public subnet so it reachable from the internet as is your case as well.

TO answer some of your question - when you deleted the IGW from the route table, your ELB automatically becomes a private subnet as such your web page stops loading.

Also, you could still see the ec2 instance behind the ELB as InService even when you deleted the IGW because the ELB and EC2 instance can communicate via the internal IP as they are in same network or VPC.

Answer (score 0):

The ELB needs a route to the internet in order to send you the response over internet.. As simple as that.

Configure your ELB in public subnet, regardless of where your instances are present.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two types of load balancers.

1)Internal
2) External

Internal load balancers are those which are launched in a private subnet which will be accessible only internally by the instances on same vpc of the internal elb

External load balancers are which are accessible over the internet which should be launched in a subnet which has internet gateway attached to it and which has route table configured properly to route the requests.

If you attach an internet gateway to a subnet it becomes a public subnet.Also if you create a load-balancer which you need to be accessible from internet it should be a External load balancer and aws will not allow it launch in a private subnet.The instances are showing in service because its communicating internally using private ip-address.